# Incremental Numbering with PHP

Tags: php

I have a website where I mention how long the company has been in business (53 years currently). I would like this number to automatically update each year. Is this possible with PHP?

Comment: yes it is possible; put  your mind to it and you'll get 'er done ;-)

Comment: If only there was a way to get the current year and subtract 1965...

Comment: `<?php echo 'at least 53!'; ?>`

Comment: Or `<?php echo 'Over 50 years in business!'; ?>`

Comment: However, if this is your customer, you may be able to get 1 hour of work every year out of them.  Don't forget about the copyright year...

Comment: @AbraCadaver Maybe a set term for a 50-year contract would be nice.

Comment: Be a couple days off due to leap years: `echo floor((time() - strtotime('1964-02-21')) / 31536000);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's no joke, one of my first bosses admitted that he would deliberately leave out features, so that his customers would hire him the next year to add them. And we were working for my father!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest taking the [founding date and current date](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), then calculating the [difference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). This will allow it to automatically update the day that the company hits its anniversary. From there, it's a simple matter of [formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) the results.

```
$foundedDate = new DateTime('1964-02-21');
$currDate = new DateTime();
$yearsOpen = $foundedDate->diff($currDate)->format('%Y');
echo $yearsOpen; //53

$foundedDate = new DateTime('1964-02-20');
$currDate = new DateTime();
$yearsOpen = $foundedDate->diff($currDate)->format('%Y');
echo $yearsOpen; //54
```

Comment: I like this one best. It's beautifully over-complicated to get the *technically* correct answer instead of the "good enough" one.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I didn't mean to make it overly complicated. If I wanted that, I'd've done some craziness with `abs()`, `floor()`, and calculating minutes/hours/days/years. ^^'

Comment: You guys are making my day. I don't understand half of this crap :) lol

Answer (score 2):

53 years currently that means the company start in `1965`

so you can use something like that:

```
echo  date("Y") - 1965;    // output: 53
```

Comment: Oh gee, you're `> <` that close to 100! Edit: Oh that changed .

Comment: Thanks for the help! I feel dumb not knowing how to do that lol

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner 109 ;)

Comment: What if the company wasn't founded on Jan 1 at midnight, though? :-p

Comment: you earned it @Ninjo ;-)

Comment: @ceejayoz: I guess subtract 1 year to be safe.

Comment: @ceejayoz *heh!*  I thought of that also earlier but I didn't say anything. It's close enough ;-) The OP can adjust if needed.

Comment: It was founded in February, close enough :)